# List of ALL Class Assignments using Graph API Beta

Tags: microsoft-graph-edu

I have been asked to retrieve all Class Assignments from Teams for education using the Graph API.

I have taken info from [educationClass Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/educationclass?view=graph-rest-beta) to list all classes, members, etc. in my ASP core console app. but I cannot get assignments due to access permissions.
It appears that the method 'List assignments' does not support the 'Application' permission type.

I then created an ASP Core Web app with Azure authentication, wired up the Graph API and was able to see a handful of assignments whilst authenticated as myself.

If I log in as a 'test' teacher then I can see their class assignments, which makes me wonder whether I could do this automatically for all teachers? Could you somehow get class assignments on behalf of a user? Ideally, this will be a console app running on a server.

I have very little experience using Graph so I am wondering whether there is a way to get the information I need. I am an O365 administrator and I was hoping this would give me access to everything I needed.

Any advise is much appreciated as I'm not sure how best to approach this task

John

Comment: This isn't supported. You can only see Assignments created by or assigned to the currently authenticated user. This is why it requires delegated permissions. In general, if your endpoint doesn't support Application scopes then it isn't a good candidate for the daemon/service model.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and confirmation.

My task is to produce a dataset to include pupilId, teacherId, class name, assignment name, assignment due date and status.
This has proven more difficult than I expected.
Having teachers log into another app to get this information would not be a practical solution, which leaves me wondering whether I could create a Teams app which gathers this information from the logged in teacher? Would this work? Could it be autonomous?